# strcasecmp in C returns 156 instead of 0, any ideas why?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have the following code:

```
printf("num: %d\n", strcasecmp(buf, "h\n"));
```

And I get the following results when I try plugging in different letters:

```
a: -7
g: -1
i: 1
j: 2
h: 156
H: 156
```

Should `strcasecmp` not return 0 when buf is equal to `H` or `h`? Any ideas why it's returning 156? I need to figure out how to check whether the user types <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>h</kbd>.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm reading buf in the following way:
`read(0, buf, MAXBUFLEN);`

Comment: How are you reading in `buf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("num: %d\n", strcasecmp(buf, "h"));
```

Why `\n` at the end, if you want to compare with `h` or `H` ?

---

```
main(){
 char *s = "hH";
 printf("%d\n", strcasecmp(s, "Hh"));
}
```

> 0

---

`read()` also stores whitespace. So, if you are using `read`, compare with "h\n".

```
main(){
 char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
 read(0, buf, 10);
 printf("%s %d %d\n", buf, strcasecmp(buf, "h\n"), strcasecmp(buf, "h"));
}
```

> h
>   h
>      0 10

I entered <kbd>h</kbd> in the above case.

Also, use `strncasecmp` if you want to compare a fixed number of characters.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I think the problem was the way I was initializing buf, there must've been some extra characters on the end of what I was trying to compare.

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing it to `"h\r\n"` - if you are on windows, both `\r` and `\n` will end a line.

Comment: I don't know about the `read` function (which I don't think is even available on Windows), but text mode streams will have newlines converted automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`read` does not put a zero at the end. It just deals with arrays of bytes, and knows nothing about null-terminated strings. So do like this:

```
char buf[MAXBUFLEN+1];
int readResult = read(0, buf, MAXBUFLEN);
if(readResult < 0)
{
    // handle error
}
else
{
    buf[readResult] = 0;
    printf("num: %d\n", strcasecmp(buf, "h\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `buf` contain a trailing newline?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
printf("num: %d\n", strcasecmp(buf, "h"));
```